# Simple object of $k[X,Y]/(Y^2)$

Tags: ct.category-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $k$ be a field. Let $A=k[X,Y]/(Y^2)$ be the quotient of polynomial ring $k[X,Y]$. Let $\mathcal{C}$ be the category of finite-dimensional $A$-modules $M$ with the action of $X$ nilpotent, and of finite projective dimension. In fact, for any $M\in\mathcal{C}$, we have $\mathrm{proj.dim}_A M\leq 1$. Then $\mathcal{C}$ is an exact category.

Let $U=k[Y]/(Y^2)$ be the quotient of $A$ by $(X)$. Then $U$ can be viewed as an $A$-module, and $U$ has finite projective dimension and is a simple object in $\mathcal{C}$. Does $\mathcal{C}$ have any other simple object? 
What is the Grothendieck group of $\mathcal{C}$?

Comment: Is it an exact category? I assume the Hom is the $A$-linear maps. The kernels of multiplicative by $Y$ seems to me that has infinite projective dimensión. Am I wrong?

Comment: It is an exact category, because the modules of finite projective dimensions are closed under taking extensions, similar for nilpotent modules. the kernel of multiplicative by Y has finite projective dimension.

Comment: I got confussed with the extensión property, because the cokernels of multiplicative by y is not of finite projective dimension. But the kernels of multiplicación by y is on infinite dimension. Just consider the periodic complex with $k[Y]/Y^2$ evewrywhwre

Comment: With multilication by $Y$ as differential, and at some point, truncate by the image of the differential.

Comment: So, you are right that you have an exact category, but the kernels of multiplicative by $Y$ is not in that category

Comment: And this is the reason why your example is a simple object in that category..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For any $\lambda\in k$, $A/(X-\lambda Y)$ is another example, I think.

Comment: But these modules have infinite projective dimension if $\lambda\neq0$.

Comment: @user142751 No, they are the cokernels of the injective maps $A\to A$ given by multiplication by $X-\lambda Y$, so they all have projective dimension one.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explaination.

Comment: Another question: what is the Grothendieck group of $\mathcal{C}$? is it free of rank one?

Comment: @user142751 I don’t know, sorry.

Comment: I thought $X$ was supposed to act nilpotently. $X$ isn't nilpotent on that module.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer $(X-\lambda Y)(X+\lambda Y)=X^2$ in $A$, since $Y^2=0$ in $A$. So $X^2$ kills the module.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what I was thinking. Jeremy Rickard is completely right.

Comment: @JeremyRickard, thank you very much.